# How to sum variables sharing a common date?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do some math with PHP and a JSON file. Basically, I have an array containing items that have a price and a sold date. **What I am attempting to do is to add the price of all the items sharing the same date.** For example, the price of all the items sold today will be summed up and the code will echo out the final price.

I have successfully retrieved the required information from my JSON file and put the price and the date in an array. I am able to call the array from outside my foreach loop.

In the code below, I am been trying a workaround to make it work, but it might require to create an array containing all of the date between x and y years, which might not be optimal.

My JSON looks like this (the format is not right)

```
Array
   [0]
        Price = 10
        Date = 1-1-2019
   [1]
        Price = 10
        Date = 2-1-2019
   [2]
        Price = 10
        Date = 2-1-2019
   [3]
        Price = 10
        Date = 1-1-2019
```

This is my PHP code

```
<?php
session_start();

$myFile = "../public/Objects.json";
$arr_data = array();

//Get data from existing json file

$jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

// converts json data into array

$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

// Fetch information in JSON

foreach($arr_data[objects] as $key=>$value){
 if ($arr_data[objects][$key][status] == "Vendu") {
  $reception_date = $arr_data[objects][$key][reception_date];
  $quantity = $arr_data[objects][$key][quantity];
  $price =  $arr_data[objects][$key][price];
  $batchprice = $price * $quantity;
  $total[$key] = array(
   "price" => $batchprice,
   "reception_date" => $reception_date
  );
  $date = "1-1-2019";
  if($total[$key][reception_date] == $date) {
   $totalprice += $total[$key][price];
  }
  else {
  }
 }
 else {
 }
}
echo "[$date, $totalprice]"; //Outputs [1-1-2019, 20]
?>
```

I expect being able to echo a list in the following format. The date would have to be from oldest to most recent or else my chart would not be working.

```
[date, price], [date, price], [date, price]...
```

I also need to convert the date format from 1-1-2019 (d-m-y) to 2000, 8, 5 (y-m-d) in order to use it in my google API chart. I think I will be able to do that by using $data = explode(*something*) and retrieving the d-m-y with $data[0]...

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You can get your desired date with php's `date()` and `strtotime()` functions. `$newDate = date("Y, m, d", strtotime($oldDate));` The format you are using [is listed in php's supported date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to sum all the prices at the same dates? And the code you posted does not work?

Comment: @shn The code I posted is not optimal since I have to write the date I want in the <?php ?> tag before being able to echo it to my website. I am looking for a code that would allow me to sum all the prices at the same date, yes.

Comment: @David It worked amazing! Thank you for helping me out with the date! The only thing left is a way to sum the prices for the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this:

```
  $total[$key] = array(
   "price" => $batchprice,
   "reception_date" => $reception_date
  );
  $date = "1-1-2019";
  if($total[$key][reception_date] == $date) {
   $totalprice += $total[$key][price];
  }
```

you could do something like this:

```
$total[$reception_date] = (isset($total[$reception_date]) ? $total[$reception_date] + $batchprice : $batchprice);
```

that should give you an array with a key of the date and value of the total price for that day.

after that, do a `usort()` on the resulting array to put them in order and then loop over the array and echo out your values.

Comment: I am so genuinely grateful for this answer! I have spent the whole day trying to figure this out and I was nowhere close! Thank you!